# My application does not appear to return any widgets

Tags: python, build, kivy, widget, overriding

I understand their are two ways to build this code and show widgets, one being using KV file and initializing root instance their for my widgets which works and another is using the build(self): method, however, for some reason it returns an empty widget screen.

I tried reading other examples in stack overflow, however still my application does not return any widgets like label or button or text input in this instance. I do not want to get my objective accomplished, by using kV file and defining root in the file for my widgets. My objective does get completed for instance if I return my widgets in the build(self) method itself, however, I want to call my MyGridLayout(GridLayout): class in the build(self): method to execute the code.

Output: the output is an empty screen, My code appears to be syntactically correct but the output shows no widgets, their does not appear to be any typos their even!

```
`
```

```
import kivy
from _distutils_hack import override
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    def __int__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Label(text='label'))
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.name)
        self.submit = Button(text="submit")
        self.add_widget(self.submit)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

`

Comment: Typo `__int__` -> `__init__`

Comment: I feel embarrassed  thanks Michael! Wow stupid me!!